# Logical meaning of "within 30 days" compared to "in 30 or fewer days" or "fewer than 30 days"

Tags: phrase-meaning, logic

As I understand it, the phrase "within 30 days" 
is the same as "in 30 or fewer days" 
not "fewer than 30 days."  Is this correct?

(I've chosen fewer instead of less because days are a quantity that I can count individually, as opposed to having less time or energy for example.)

Comment: I would read the first as referring to a deadline, the second referring to a total accumulation of days spent.  For example, "This project must be finished within 30 days" is different than "This project must be finished in 30 days or fewer." - The first establishes a "date"  the second just establishes a duration/or level of effort.

Comment: Good clarification.  The context refers to hospital readmissions.  Hospitals are penalized if a patient is readmitted within 30 days after the discharge date. Therefore if a patient returns in 30 or fewer days after discharge, it's a ding on the record.  Fewer than 30 equals a maximum of 29 days. right?

Comment: I strongly suggest that you include your comment in the question itself for context. I know exactly what you're referring to, now, but didn't before.  The question needs to be able to stand on its own, and your comment will ensure that. I believe that the answer is yes, fewer than 30 days equals a maximum of 29, as hospital charges are not done in fractional numbers.

Comment: Take it to the limit:  "within 1 day".  Does that mean in 0 or fewer days, or 1 or fewer days?

Comment: 'In 30 days or less' is idiomatic, as with 'It's 30 miles or less'; the timespan is non-discrete, and such expressions are usually treated as mass rather than count. Even in obviously count situations, the usual choice is not always 'fewer': 'That's one less problem'. // 'Within x days' means 'before the (x + 1)th day'.

Comment: So is the whole point of this question just whether the limit is inclusive or exclusive? I suspect there's not a widespread concensus, and the phrase is ambiguous.

Comment: The meaning is dependent upon context.

Answer (score 1):

Within 30 days = You have no more than 30 days. (By itself this does not clarify when the start date or end date is).

Within 30 days of the expiration date = You have a period of 30 days before the expiration date (inclusive).

You must file the form it during the 30-day period immediately before the expiration date = further clarifies that you must file the form inside of that 30 day just before the expiration date (inclusive).

Answer (score 0):

**Background**

According to Strunk and White (Macmillan, 1979, page 51):

> **Less**. Should not be confused with *fewer*.
>
> Left-hand column: He had less men than in the previous campaign.
>   [incorrect]
>
> Right-hand column: He had fewer men than in the previous campaign.
>   [correct]
>
> *Less* refers to quantity, *fewer* to number. "His troubles are less than
>   mine" means "His troubles are not so great as mine." "His troubles are
>   fewer than mine, means "His troubles are not so numerous as mine."

**The OP's Question**

From a grammatical standpoint:

- **Within 30 days** means *within any duration of time less than or equal to 30 days (measured from some starting point)*.  The following
  would all meet the requirement of **within 30 days**: 1 day,
  3.14159265358979... days, 29 days, 29 1/2 days, 29.314159265358979... days.
- **Within 30 days or *less*** means exactly the same thing as **within 30 days**. That is, the "or less"" is superfluous; it doesn't add
  anything.
- **Within 30 or *fewer* days** means *within 30 days, within 29 days, within 28 days, ..., within 1 day. It also means exactly the same
  thing as **within 30 days**. That is, the "or fewer days* is
  superfluous; it doesn't add anything.

So, it would seem that **within 30 days**, **within 30 days or less**, and **within 30 days or fewer** mean exactly the same thing: **within 30 days**, i.e., *within any duration of time less than or equal to 30 days (measured from some starting point)*.

If one were to use *in* rather than *within*, the "or less" and "or fewer* matter. For example:

- **In 30 days** means "come back in 30 days" or "submit the form in 30 days", i.e., after 30 days have gone by.
- **In 30 days or less** means exactly the same thing as **within 30 days**.

Comment: *Less* has been used to refer to number for more than a thousand years; the idea that it should not be is relatively recent and started as one person's opinion. Either way I don't think it makes sense to lead with information about *less* versus *fewer*, the question wasn't about that.

Answer (score 0):

I believe "within 30 days of Dec. 31 mean within 30 **after** Dec. 31 and 30 day **before** Dec. 31st

ie anytime between December 1st and January 30th

Comment: In what context?  Amortization?  Please give a citation to justify your answer, and please feel free to take a [tour] of the site and read the [FAQ].